# AsyncPostBackTrigger in a Repeater outside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater, webforms, asynchronous-postback

I am trying to get a `cbxSupplement` trigger updatepanel refresh, but am not sure if I am using a wrong `EventName` or it is just impossible to do it with `CheckBox`. If I replace `CheckBox` with `Button`, it works fine.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSupplements" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxSupplement" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="repSupplements" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        //Get checked items
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `CheckBox` controls inside repeater are not available at design time you should register them with [ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method. This method requires `ScriptManager` either on page or on master page.

Create a handler for `Repeater.OnItemCreated` event and there register newly created `CheckBox`. The code is following (note that `CheckBox` should have `AutoPostBack` property set to true):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSupplements" runat="server" 
    OnItemCreated="repSupplements_ItemCreated">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxSupplement" AutoPostBack="True" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
    <Triggers>

    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        //Get checked items
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void repSupplements_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var control = e.Item.FindControl("cbxSupplement");
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(control);
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: What is the page ??